# Vue 3 - Vite app missing some CSS rules after build

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, build, vite

So, I've been struggling really hard on this, been working for a long time on a big update for my app, everything runs smooth and great on development, but once I build for production some of the CSS rules are missing, some elements are not ok, colors aren't showing as they should, and flexbox seems off...

So let me start from the beginning:

**Evironment:**

- Vite 2.6.11
- Vue 3.2.20
- ref sugar
- Firebase Hosting

Here are my dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "30.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "2.0.1",
    "@hennge/vue3-pagination": "^1.0.17",
    "@iconify/iconify": "2.0.4",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "4.7.4",
    "@popperjs/core": "2.10.2",
    "@vueform/multiselect": "2.2.0",
    "@vueform/slider": "2.0.5",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.21",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.18",
    "@vueuse/core": "6.7.3",
    "@vueuse/head": "0.6.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "ant-design-vue": "^2.2.8",
    "apexcharts": "3.28.3",
    "axios": "0.22.0",
    "billboard.js": "3.1.5",
    "bulma": "0.9.3",
    "bulma-css-vars": "0.7.0",
    "dayjs": "1.10.7",
    "dragula": "3.7.3",
    "dropzone": "5.9.3",
    "filepond": "4.30.3",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size": "2.2.5",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "1.2.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-crop": "2.0.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-edit": "1.6.3",
    "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "1.0.11",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "4.6.10",
    "filepond-plugin-image-resize": "2.0.10",
    "filepond-plugin-image-transform": "3.8.7",
    "firebase": "9.1.3",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
    "imask": "6.2.2",
    "mapbox-gl": "2.5.0",
    "markdown-it-emoji": "2.0.0",
    "notyf": "3.10.0",
    "nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "photoswipe": "4.1.3",
    "pinia": "^2.0.0-rc.15",
    "pinia-plugin-persist": "^0.0.92",
    "qrcode-vue3": "^1.4.17",
    "simple-datatables": "3.1.2",
    "simplebar": "6.0.0-beta.10",
    "simplebar-vue": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "stylelint-csstree-validator": "^1.9.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.16.7",
    "tiny-slider": "2.9.3",
    "tippy.js": "6.3.2",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "v-calendar": "3.0.0-alpha.5",
    "v-offline": "^3.0.0",
    "vant": "^3.2.6",
    "vee-validate": "4.5.4",
    "vivus": "0.4.6",
    "vue": "3.2.20",
    "vue-accessible-color-picker": "3.0.0",
    "vue-currency-input": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-i18n": "9.2.0-beta.15",
    "vue-router": "4.0.12",
    "vue-scrollto": "2.20.0",
    "vue-stripe-menu": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-tippy": "6.0.0-alpha.33",
    "vue-toastification": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "1.4.1",
    "vue3-burger-menu": "^1.1.1",
    "vue3-carousel": "^0.1.28",
    "vue3-clipboard": "^1.0.0",
    "vueperslides": "^3.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.3",
    "yup": "0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "13.2.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "13.2.0",
    "@commitlint/prompt-cli": "13.2.0",
    "@iconify/json": "1.1.410",
    "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "2.4.0",
    "@types/dragula": "3.7.1",
    "@types/luxon": "^1.27.1",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "2.4.2",
    "@types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-geocoder": "4.7.1",
    "@types/markdown-it": "12.2.1",
    "@types/node": "16.10.2",
    "@types/nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "@types/photoswipe": "4.1.2",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.16.6",
    "@types/simplebar": "5.3.3",
    "@types/vivus": "0.4.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.33.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "1.9.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "3.2.20",
    "autoprefixer": "9.8.6",
    "commitlint": "13.2.0",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "cypress": "8.5.0",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-md": "1.0.19",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility": "^0.7.1",
    "gray-matter": "4.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "11.2.0",
    "markdown-it": "12.2.0",
    "markdown-it-anchor": "8.3.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "plyr": "3.6.8",
    "postcss-nested": "4.2.3",
    "prettier": "2.4.1",
    "prismjs": "1.25.0",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "rollup": "2.58.3",
    "rollup-plugin-purgecss": "^4.0.3",
    "sass": "1.32.13",
    "standard-version": "9.3.2",
    "stylelint": "13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "22.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.21.0",
    "typescript": "4.4.3",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "0.16.0",
    "vfonts": "^0.1.0",
    "vite": "2.6.11",
    "vite-imagetools": "3.6.8",
    "vite-plugin-fonts": "0.2.2",
    "vite-plugin-imagemin": "0.4.6",
    "vite-plugin-pages": "0.18.1",
    "vite-plugin-purge-icons": "0.7.0",
    "vite-plugin-pwa": "0.11.3",
    "vite-plugin-radar": "0.2.0",
    "vite-svg-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-tsc": "0.3.0",
    "yorkie": "2.0.0"
  }
```

Here is my vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
// @ts-ignore
import path from 'path'
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import ViteFonts from 'vite-plugin-fonts'
import ViteRadar from 'vite-plugin-radar'
import PurgeIcons from 'vite-plugin-purge-icons'
import { imagetools } from 'vite-imagetools'
import ImageMin from 'vite-plugin-imagemin'
import { vueI18n } from '@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n'
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'
import purgecss from 'rollup-plugin-purgecss'
import ViteComponents, {
  AntDesignVueResolver,
  VantResolver
} from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'

const SILENT = Boolean(process.env.SILENT) ?? false
const SOURCE_MAP = Boolean(process.env.SOURCE_MAP) ?? false

/**
 * This is the main configuration file for vitejs
 *
 * @see https://vitejs.dev/config
 */
export default defineConfig({
  // Project root directory (where index.html is located).
  root: process.cwd(),
  // Base public path when served in development or production.
  // You also need to add this base like `history: createWebHistory('my-subdirectory')`
  // in ./src/router.ts
  // base: '/my-subdirectory/',
  base: '/',
  // Directory to serve as plain static assets.
  publicDir: 'public',
  // Adjust console output verbosity.
  logLevel: SILENT ? 'error' : 'info',
  /**
   * By default, Vite will crawl your index.html to detect dependencies that
   * need to be pre-bundled. If build.rollupOptions.input is specified,
   * Vite will crawl those entry points instead.
   *
   * @see https://vitejs.dev/config/#optimizedeps-entries
   */
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: [
      '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue',
      '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic',
      '@iconify/iconify',
      '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js',
      '@vueuse/core',
      '@vueuse/head',
      '@vueform/multiselect',
      '@vueform/slider',
      'axios',
      'billboard.js',
      'dayjs',
      'dropzone',
      'dragula',
      'filepond',
      'filepond-plugin-file-validate-size',
      'filepond-plugin-file-validate-type',
      'filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation',
      'filepond-plugin-image-crop',
      'filepond-plugin-image-edit',
      'filepond-plugin-image-preview',
      'filepond-plugin-image-resize',
      'filepond-plugin-image-transform',
      'imask',
      'nprogress',
      'notyf',
      'mapbox-gl',
      'photoswipe/dist/photoswipe',
      'photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default',
      'plyr',
      'v-calendar',
      'vee-validate',
      'vue',
      'vue-scrollto',
      'vue3-apexcharts',
      'vue-tippy',
      'simplebar',
      'simple-datatables',
      'tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider',
      'vue-accessible-color-picker',
      'yup',
      'ant-design-vue',
      'vant'
    ],
  },
  // Will be passed to @rollup/plugin-alias as its entries option.
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: '/~/',
        replacement: `/src/assets/`,
      },
      {
        find: '/@src/',
        replacement: `/src/`,
      },
    ],
  },

  build: {
    sourcemap: SOURCE_MAP,
    // Turning off brotliSize display can slightly reduce packaging time
    brotliSize: !SILENT,
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 2000,
    minify: 'esbuild',
    cssCodeSplit: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    /**
     * plugin-vue plugin inject vue library and allow sfc files to work (*.vue)
     *
     * @see https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/plugin-vue
     */
    Vue({
      include: [/\.vue$/],
    }),

    /**
     * vite-plugin-vue-i18n plugin does i18n resources pre-compilation / optimizations
     *
     * @see https://github.com/intlify/bundle-tools/tree/main/packages/vite-plugin-vue-i18n
     */
    vueI18n({
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/locales/**'),
    }),

    /**
     * unplugin-vue-components plugin is responsible of autoloading components
     * documentation and md file are loaded for elements and components sections
     *
     * @see https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components
     */
    Components({
      dirs: ['src/components', 'src/layouts', 'src/views'],
      extensions: ['vue', 'md'],
      dts: true,
      include: [/\.vue$/, /\.vue\?vue/, /\.md$/],
      resolvers: [
        AntDesignVueResolver(),
        VantResolver()
      ]
    }),

    /**
     * vite-plugin-purge-icons plugin is responsible of autoloading icones from multiples providers
     *
     * @see https://icones.netlify.app/
     * @see https://github.com/antfu/purge-icons/tree/main/packages/vite-plugin-purge-icons
     */
    PurgeIcons(),

    /**
     * vite-plugin-fonts plugin inject webfonts from differents providers
     *
     * @see https://github.com/stafyniaksacha/vite-plugin-fonts
     */
    ViteFonts({
      google: {
        families: [
          {
            name: 'Fira Code',
            styles: 'wght@400;600',
          },
          {
            name: 'Montserrat',
            styles: 'wght@500;600;700;800;900',
          },
          {
            name: 'Roboto',
            styles: 'wght@300;400;500;600;700',
          },
        ],
      },
    }),

    /**
     * vite-plugin-radar plugin inject snippets from analytics providers
     *
     * @see https://github.com/stafyniaksacha/vite-plugin-radar
     */
    ViteRadar({
      analytics: {
        id: '',
      },
    }),

    /**
     * vite-plugin-pwa generate manifest.json and register services worker to enable PWA
     *
     * @see https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-pwa
     */
    VitePWA({
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      base: '/',
      includeAssets: [
        'favicon.svg',
        'favicon.ico',
        'robots.txt',
        'apple-touch-icon.png',
      ],
      manifest: {
        name: 'Treebū Admin',
        short_name: 'Treebū Admin',
        start_url: '/?utm_source=pwa',
        display: 'standalone',
        theme_color: '#ffffff',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        icons: [
          {
            src: 'pwa-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: 'pwa-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: 'pwa-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png',
            purpose: 'any maskable',
          },
        ],
      },
    }),

    /**
     * rollup-plugin-purgecss plugin is responsible of purging css rules
     * that are not used in the bundle
     *
     * @see https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/tree/main/packages/rollup-plugin-purgecss
     */
    purgecss({
      content: [`./src/**/*.vue`],
      variables: false,
      safelist: {
        standard: [
          /(autv|lnil|lnir|fas?)/,
          /-(leave|enter|appear)(|-(to|from|active))$/,
          /^(?!(|.*?:)cursor-move).+-move$/,
          /^router-link(|-exact)-active$/,
          /data-v-.*/,
        ],
      },
      defaultExtractor(content) {
        const contentWithoutStyleBlocks = content.replace(
          /<style[^]+?<\/style>/gi,
          ''
        )
        return (
          contentWithoutStyleBlocks.match(/[A-Za-z0-9-_/:]*[A-Za-z0-9-_/]+/g) ||
          []
        )
      },
    }),

    /**
     * vite-imagetools plugin allow to perform transformation (blur, resize, crop, etc)
     * on images at build time
     *
     * @see https://github.com/JonasKruckenberg/vite-imagetools
     */
    imagetools({
      silent: SILENT,
    }),

    /**
     * vite-plugin-imagemin optimize all images sizes from public or asset folder
     *
     * @see https://github.com/anncwb/vite-plugin-imagemin
     */
    ImageMin({
      verbose: !SILENT,
      gifsicle: {
        optimizationLevel: 7,
        interlaced: false,
      },
      optipng: {
        optimizationLevel: 7,
      },
      mozjpeg: {
        quality: 60,
      },
      pngquant: {
        quality: [0.8, 0.9],
        speed: 4,
      },
      svgo: {
        plugins: [
          {
            name: 'removeViewBox',
            active: false,
          },
          {
            name: 'removeEmptyAttrs',
            active: false,
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!--iOS configuration-->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <meta name="google" content="notranslate">

    <!--ICONS-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/mobile-icons/ios/apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/images/mobile-icons/ios/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/images/mobile-icons/ios/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/images/mobile-icons/ios/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/images/mobile-icons/ios/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/images/mobile-icons/ios/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/images/mobile-icons/ios/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/images/mobile-icons/ios/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/images/mobile-icons/ios/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/images/mobile-icons/ios/apple-icon-180x180.png">

    <!--    Splashscreen-->
    <link href="/images/splashscreens/iphone5_splash.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="/images/splashscreens/iphone6_splash.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="/images/splashscreens/iphoneplus_splash.png" media="(device-width: 621px) and (device-height: 1104px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="/images/splashscreens/iphonex_splash.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="/images/splashscreens/iphonexr_splash.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="/images/splashscreens/iphonexsmax_splash.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="/images/splashscreens/ipad_splash.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="/images/splashscreens/ipadpro1_splash.png" media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="/images/splashscreens/ipadpro3_splash.png" media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
    <link href="/images/splashscreens/ipadpro2_splash.png" media="(device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />

    <!--Status Bar-->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#2f3048">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
    <link
      rel="apple-toucv-icon"
      sizes="180x180"
      href="/icons/apple-touch-icon.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="/icons/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="16x16"
      href="/icons/favicon-16x16.png"
    />
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#232326" />
    <!--    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />-->
    <title>Treebū Hotels</title>
    <script>
      /**
       * this is a hack for dragula used on KanbanApp
       *
       * @see src/components/pages/apps/KanbanApp.vue
       */
      var global = global || window
    </script>
    <link
      rel="preload"
      as="style"
      onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"
      href="/vendors/font-awesome-v5.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      as="style"
      onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"
      href="/vendors/line-icons-pro.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      as="style"
      onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"
      href="/vendors/prism-coldark-cold.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-teleport-bg></div>
    <div id="app" class="app-wrapper"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/styles.ts"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please note the differences in the following images between the dev version and the production version:

Dev Version:

[image: Dev version]

Prod Version:
[image: Prod version]

As you can see there is a mismatch in styles... lets continue:

Dev version, flexbox working correctly:
[image]
[image]

No flexbox in prod version
[image]

[image]

There are no warnings or errors on console on the build version,

I have tried removing antd, vant, and other custom css styles, just in case there is some conflict, but I get the same result, also tried with

minify: 'esbuild', // or false

cssCodeSplit: true, //or false

In the vite.config

Everything works perfectly on development but it's just messed up on build.

Any hints? ideas? possibilities? chances?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with this same issue now. If you have a solution I'd be quite thankful. Thanks

Comment: For me, after I ran `npm run preview`, the styles were messed up, but this remained even after going back to `npm run serve`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind lost CSS is purgecss library. When building for production, it removes CSS rules that are not being used.

There are some libraries that concatenate CSS class names using JS to define certain looks. Those end-result classes defined in CSS tend to get purged, because purgecss doesn't see them as being used while building up.

To solve this issue, once you discover which classes are getting purged, you can whitelist them.

You can set whitelist patterns in postcss.config.js file, located next to vite.config.js.

Since I can not know which specific library is causing your issues, I will show an example I was having with vue-multiselect library, and the way I solved it:

**index.scss*

```
@import "~vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css";
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
whitelistPatterns: [
            ...
            /multiselect*/,
        ]
```

*Please note that in newer Vite versions, whitelistPatterns is replaced by **safelist***

*More about whitelisting https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html*

Answer (score 0):

for me this happened when `minify` was set to false, e.g.:

```js
build: {
  minify: env.mode !== "development", // flase for development mode
}
```

it was fixed when I added `cssCodeSplit: false`, i.e.

```js
build: {
  minify: env.mode !== "development",
  cssCodeSplit: env.mode === "development" ? false : undefined
}
```

*note*, I used `undefined` in non-development mode, so it takes the default rather than `true`

*note 2* I do not understand why this is happening, but this is how I resolved it

Comment: env is not defined

Comment: `env` is defined for me as part of the function, but it doesn't matter for the purpose of this

Answer (score -4):

I had also the same problem as yours, So I searched about it and found a solution to it.

I just ran `npm run hot` this command and by doing this, the issue had been resolved

Comment: I don't have that command in my packages.js, what's that supposed to do? and can you share what the script is?

Comment: Can you please tell me that how are you attaching your CSS files to the main app.css file ?

Comment: It is added in the index.html from a master file called styles.ts, where I do import all SASS and CSS styles... the thing, is... this was working just like this before, but now it doesnt... i don't think ``npm run hot`` it's the solution, I'm using VITE, just for the records.

Comment: `npm run hot` is working for laravel mix, but as you are saying that you are using VITE so, it will be difficult for me to give the proper answer, so sorry for that

Comment: in any case, the error happens when building the app not on dev, so… hot reload has nothing to do with the build itself.